Boot code error creating WinPE drive
I'm trying to create a USB WinPE drive. I used copype to put the environment in the C:\winpe folder, and prepped my flash drive in MBR mode with a 2000 MB FAT32 partition for drive letter D: at the front of drive. This is a 64 GB flash drive, but the remaining space will be used for other things and is formatted as exfat.
I then run this makewinpemedia command to copy from C:\winpe to the D: drive:
makewinpemedia /ufd /f c:\winpe d:

But I see this error:

ERROR: Failed to set the boot code on d:.


I've tried everything I can think of, including downloading and installing a fresh copy of the Windows ADT toolkits on a separate computer and running from there, but nothing helps. I don't see anything in the Event Viewer. Googling this specific error message gets me nowhere; there's only one blog article from 2016 where the message is slightly different. (I tried the suggestion anyway with no change).
How can I fix this?

So I tried this on a fourth computer and things went through. Not sure what changed :/
